# How to prevent date conversion to local time zone with DayJS

Tags: javascript, date, time, dayjs

I have a date string `const someDate = 2023-02-13T09:00:00.000-05:00`

The problem is when I'm formatting it via DayJS.

`dayjs(someDate).format('h:mm A')`

It returns me string according to my local time zone, when I need to keep like I received.

Any way to disable converting time to local timezone in DayJS?

Comment: see the docs [converting to zone](https://day.js.org/docs/en/timezone/converting-to-zone)

Comment: It looks like you want to load this date as utc https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/utc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes!

You can disable converting to local timezone in dayjs by passing in the original timezone as an additional argument in the dayjs constructor.

**Example:**

```
const someDate = "2023-02-13T09:00:00.000-05:00";
const originalTimezone = someDate.slice(-6);
const formattedDate = dayjs(someDate).utcOffset(originalTimezone).format('h:mm A');
```

The `utcOffset()` method allows you to set the offset in minutes from UTC for a specific date instance. The `originalTimezone` constant is used to extract the timezone offset `(-05:00)` from the original date string `someDate`, and pass it to the `utcOffset()` method. This will ensure that the formatted date stays in the original timezone.

Comment: Extremely underrated answer that should be in the dayjs docs!

Comment: While this achieves the goal, technically it's not disabling local time zone conversion, it's just immediately converting it back.  It's also not passing the offset in the construct, but rather making a separate function call after the object has been constructed.

Comment: See also https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/issues/651 for discussion and alternate implementation as a dayjs plugin.

Comment: Thanks for weighing in @MattJohnson-Pint  -- I notice that when I do this method without formatting, and I get the full ISO string, it's still in GMT (which at the moment is also the TZ my machine is set to). Can someone explain why `format` reflects the TZ I want but the unformatted output does not? It is actually more like `formatInGivenTimezone`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [utc](https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/utc) plugin.

```
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import utc from 'dayjs/plugin/utc';

dayjs.extend(utc)


const dateTime = "2023-02-13T09:00:00.000-05:00";
const value = dayjs.utc(dateTime).format('h:mm A');

console.log(value);
```

Comment: Does this not just convert it to its equivalent time at GMT? (`"2023-02-13T14:00:00.000-00:00"`)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the simplest way is to actually supply both an "input" and "output" TZ:

```js
const twoThirtyThreeNoMatterWhat = dayjs('02-05-21 02:33 PM GMT').tz('GMT').format(FMT),
```

This is essentially the same as @Filip Huhta but doesn't require parsing the offset -- although you could of course hardcode the offset so that his answer becomes

```js
const formattedDate = dayjs(someDate).utcOffset('-5:00').format('h:mm A');
```

Which is certainly fine, although it's a few more characters than mine.

The important thing, though, is that because they are both the same, they don't matter as long as they are both the same.

Of course, this only works if you really have control of the input. If, say, you're calling `dayjs` with some text you've parsed, then you can call that function with whatever exact string you want. And I'd assert that that is *usually* the case.

I also suppose my strategy is only valid if you in fact *do not* care about the time zone. Since your desired format is `h:mm A` then I imagine you simply want it to say `9:00 AM` and that's all you care about. (I'd also assert that *this* is usually the case )